The purpose of adding a plugin with "apply false" to the root project with version catalogs?
When following the instructions for migrating Jetpack Compose compiler to the dedicated Compose compiler Gradle plugin, I found this step a bit confusing:


Add the Gradle plugin to the root build.gradle.kts file:

plugins {
   // ...
   alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
}


The plugin itself is actually applied with same exact version in each submodule:


Apply the plugin to every module that uses Jetpack Compose:

plugins {
    // ...
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
}


To me, step 2 seems redundant:

the plugin itself doesn't execute anything in the root project
the version of the plugin has already been shared through the version catalog itself, so there is no need to share the version once again through the root project
everything actually works when alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false is removed

I see that this pattern of defining the plugins in the root without applying them is quite widespread. It is used in the default Android project templates. Also, I found some samples specifically following this style for all plugins: e.g. Jetsnack
Does anyone know what value these extra lines of code alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false actually bring? I cannot find an answer myself.

I can't speak on Android or that specific plugin specifics, but the syntax apply false means to resolve the plugin, but don't apply the plugin.
Resolving means resolve the plugin itself and any associated dependencies for that plugin. This makes the plugin code, classpath, and its dependencies available for use in the build script. This is useful to reuse task classes from a plugin or to apply it to some other target than the current script.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
